# Reshape multidimensional array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have an array representing hourly temperature data, and want to compute daily maxima (or minima, or means).  I can do this using a for loop, but I am sure there must be many better ways to do this in R.

```
require(ncdf4)
nc <- nc_open('file.nc')
t2 <- ncvar_get(nc,var='T2')  # [ncols, nrows, nsteps]
```

Now t2 is an array with 744 hourly time steps for a 31-day month.  What I want is:

```
t2.max[ncols, nrows, 31]
```

or, more generally, I would like to reshape t2 to:

```
t2.reshape[ncols, nrows, ndays, 24]
```

and from there I can use apply to compute daily means or maxima or whatever.

I want the result to be an array, not a data frame.

Suggestions?  I tried using melt/cast from the reshape package, but could not understand how to specify the desired formula.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If t2 is an array with 744 hourly time steps for a 31-day month" then it has 744 rows and other dimensions? (You did not tell us whether ncol was 744 or nrow was 744. We will assume it was nrow)

```
 array( tc, , dim =c( 31, 24, nrows,  ncols) )
```

If, on the other hand, it was  [nrow,ncols,744] you can use aperm to recast it with the rows being as above:

```
 array( aperm(tc, c(3,1,2)) , dim =c( 31, 24, nrows,  ncols) )
```

There is a package that has a 'rowMax' and and a 'rowMin' function which would give you a vectorized approach that you would not need to invent. (It was in the Biobase package from the Bioconductor repository.)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The number of hours varies faster than the number of days, so I needed instead: `array( aperm(t2,dim=c(3,1,2)), dim=c( 24, 31, nrows, ncols) )`.